# How to update two fields database with same data

Tags: mysql

Importing a csv file with 4 fields/columns per row, 20,000 rows. One column is empty and I would like it to be filled with the data going into the first field with ".jpg" added to it. how would I best do this please?

Comment: Which tool are you using to do the import?

Answer (score 0):

so just update and set the column like this

```
UPDATE tablename
SET column4 = CONCAT(column1, '.jpg')
```

aka run this query after the import